# Exporting PSQL 9.4.4 table to CSV

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, command-line, psql

I have a PSQL database and would like to export one table to CSV. Here is what I'm using:

```
COPY store_events TO '/home/[my_name]/public_html/export.csv' 
WITH FORMAT csv DELIMITER ',' HEADER
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. I get the following error:

> syntax error at or near "FORMAT"

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: You dont need WITH FORMAT, `COPY store_events TO '/home/[my_name]/public_html/export.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER`

Comment: @Mihai When I put this line, it just goes to the next prompt line without giving any error message, and the CSV is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the syntax in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html):

```
COPY buffer TO '/home/[my_name]/public_html/export.csv' 
WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', HEADER);
```

Comment: When I put this line, it just goes to the next prompt line without giving any error message, and the CSV is not populated.

Comment: Add semicolon at the end of the statement.

Comment: I just added the semicolon and now I get this error: syntax error at or near "("

Comment: Merge two lines into one (you have executed only second line).

Comment: It's in one line, I made sure I copied the whole thing you gave me. :)

Comment: This works with no errors: `COPY store_events TO '/home/faridj/public_html/export.csv' DELIMITER ',';` but the CSV that gets produced has some formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

For psql use

```
copy store_events to '/home/[my_name]/public_html/export.csv' with csv
```

Comment: I get the following error: syntax error at or near "csv"